# CSS not being applied to new site

Tags: iis-6, css

I'm so far from my main expertise I can possibly get - doing server admin and web/css.

I have 3 sites in play - Live, Beta and new test site that should resemble the New World coming. (because we're about to upgrade everything on the live/beta site - hardware, software, location). New World coming - MS SQL2008, IIS 6, MS Server2008. It will until further notice continue to run .NET 3.5.

New test site has the same source code as beta.

Beta and Live has nice CSS.
New test site are missing out on the CSS.

I found a note about checking security rights - I did, first on the themes folder and just for the IIS_IUSR, next for all folders and user Everyone (Yes I removed those rights again).

Firebug says it has found the main.css file and style.css, they are just empty. If I edit it and copy paste the css from Beta/Live I get something that resembles the right solution.

I tried starting Explorer, same issue. Tried clearing the caches (explorer and firefox) - same result.

I tried going through the server settings and copying all I find to the new site.

I have where I get the css in question

> public static string CssFilePath
>   {
>      get
>      {
>          return Path.Combine
>          (Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
>          , @"App_Themes\our\main.css");
>      }
>   }

Paths are 100% identical between Live and new test site, while Beta has beta in folder name.
Live: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\our.dk\www
Test: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\our.dk\www
Beta: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beta.our.dk\www

What I'm looking for is keywords I can google, articles that deals with why aren't the CSS being applied.

I found loads of sites describing how you can learn CSS, why this or that tag is written wrong (ex. {} pair).

Comment: I just found one place it says test site is running IIS 7, the other About UIs says its version 6. Hopefully I'm running IIS 7.

Comment: I just found, I can't add any images till I get 10 rep points.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please let us know the Exact error if you are getting?

Comment: I am per say not getting a direct error, meaning I load the pages. The css is just not applied, meaning it does not have the colors specified. Some of the items are placed in the right spot, while others are not. I'll get some SS to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your cache server which prevent your browser to get new CSS file and the Cache Server stuck with old CSS. I suggest to add a random number at the end of your .css file path. It can trick the Cache server to think it's new file. Here is how I do it in PHP:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://sample.com/style.css  <?php echo "?q=".mt_rand(1, 1000000) ?>" type="text/css">
```

Because http://sample.com/.style.css?345255 is different than sample.com/.style.css?987434 Cache server all time get the new css from the server.

You should remove this mechanism when you are deploying your website because it can reduce speed of page load for the end users.